# Subclassing Widgets with complex signatures

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

As far as I found out, `RadioListTile` with `Text` als child has unlimited with.

As a helper class, I'd like to subclass `RadioListTile` with a default `Text` child of defined **maximum width**.

Unfortunately, `RadioListTile` has a very complex constructor.

Does a best practice exist, how to create a **specialized RadioListTile** and somehow **abstract from the complex constructor signature**?

Constructor of `RadioListTile`:

```
  const RadioListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.groupValue,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.toggleable = false,
    this.activeColor,
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.isThreeLine = false,
    this.dense,
    this.secondary,
    this.selected = false,
    this.controlAffinity = ListTileControlAffinity.platform,
    this.autofocus = false,
    this.contentPadding,
    this.shape,
    this.tileColor,
    this.selectedTileColor,
    this.visualDensity,
    this.focusNode,
    this.enableFeedback,
  })
```

**Another example**

Suppose I frequently use this snippet:

```
Text( 'Tabelle', style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.fontWeight,
              fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.fontSize,
            ) )
```

I Imagine to use a specialized Text() widget like so:

```
TextBodyMedium( 'Tabelle' )
```

Ho do I orderly specialize the Text() class without enumerating all its 10+ parameters? Does a canonical way exist?

Comment: Be sure to check constructor argument forwarding in Dart 2.17, it made the syntax twice as short: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#super-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2022-05-12:** With Dart 2.17, passing arguments to superclass constructor is twice as short, see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#super-parameters
Everything else below still applies.

**Original answer:**

In Dart, there is no way to automatically pass all the arguments to a superclass. For instance, this is how `Column` widget is implemented (it is a `Flex` widget with vertical direction):

```dart
  Column({
    Key? key,
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    MainAxisSize mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    VerticalDirection verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    List<Widget> children = const <Widget>[],
  }) : super(
    children: children,
    key: key,
    direction: Axis.vertical,
    mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
    mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
    crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
    textDirection: textDirection,
    verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
    textBaseline: textBaseline,
  );
```

This is why you don't see that many packages that customize standard widgets a little bit.

If you use a customized widget it in your app and do not export it as a library, you probably do not need 80% of those arguments. So in practice we create widgets that only accept the arguments we need.

Speaking of giving a finite width to `RadioListTile`. There is a purpose why it is infinite and does not accept a width. In a good design, there should be only one way of setting width. One could think of automatically determining width from the container or of passing it explicitly. For many reasons in Flutter the former was chosen. Some of the benefits include automatic layout on resizing, avoidance of property drills, and less need for customized widgets. So I suggest you allow the container of your radio to determine width. That way you get rid of the whole class `MyRadioListTile`.

As for `TextBodyMedium`, I suggest you first shorten it like this:

```dart
Text('Tabelle', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium);
```

Next, if you need to use a lot of that on one page, you can use `DefaultTextStyle` widget to apply the style to all widgets beneath it in the tree.

Comment: Thx! Let's see, if others provide other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think Alexey Inkin's in the right answer, but if you want a way to have some standard value for one parameter (text with a fixed width in this case) while still having access to the many other properties you could try a pattern like the code below. It's slightly more verbose in usage than simple composition (or inheritance) but you retain access to all of `RadioListTile` parameters.

```
class MyTextBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextBuilder({
    required this.text,
    required this.builder,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final RadioListTile Function(BuildContext context, Widget child) builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => builder(
        context,
        SizedBox(width: 100, child: Text(text)),
      );
}

// Usage:

final example = MyTextBuilder(
  text: "Hello",
  builder: (context, value) => RadioListTile(
    value: value,
    // any of the other plethora of parameters 
  ),
);
```